# Meaning of "but don’t hold your breath"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "but don’t hold your breath" as "but don’t hold your expectations too high."  Am I on the right track?

> Unexpected results from the Large Hadron Collider might point to new physics – **but don’t hold your breath**.
>
> Source: [New Scientist](https://twitter.com/newscientist/status/1376052800333942785) on Twitter

Comment: In my opinion this has more to do with time taken to see that new physics rather than its highness. To hold the breath suggests a relatively short time to elaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Don't hold your breath!" is a casual way to say that something may take longer than you want.

Most scientists are interested and excited by the idea that there has been a discovery at CERN.  They want this discovery to be confirmed soon.  But, it will take a long time to confirm this result.

> The new government has promised a tax cut, but don't hold your breath; the Prime Minister says it will be several years before the economy is strong enough for a tax cut.